# Movie about army reserve soldiers on rotation and they are stranded with combat knives

Tags: identify-this-movie

I am trying to remember the name of a movie where there is a group of soldiers from the reserve (or health backup? but there is indeed a doctor/paramedic guy in the group). They go out in rotation (I think for up 60 days). The only scene I do remember is that they are out of ammo on one side of a hill (small sandy slope).

On the other side are the enemies who are either talking around a pickup truck or trying to fix it. The enemies hear a noise from the hill and decide to inspect it.

The reserve soldiers notice this and since they out of ammo, the big group of them (I think they are up 7 soldiers) decide to pull their combat knives and attack the enemies the moment they come over the hill. So for next few minutes we have multiple 1 on 1 battles with combat knives.

I place the intensity of the scene just below that of American GI versus the German soldier in saving Private Ryan. Except the Americans actually win this time.

Location? Maybe Iraq war but don't put too much concentration on this or I may lead you off track.

Timeline? The movie most likely came out after 2000.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many similarities with [American Soldiers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0425743/). See trailer below

Comment: Oh man that's the one! You are awesome. I have been trying to remember this for a good year or more.

Comment: @GertArnold Video doesn't exists anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it is borrowed from 1981's [Southern Comfort](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083111/combined) with Powers Boothe and Keith Carradine, a decent thriller about a squad of National Guard soldiers on maneuvers who run into some country boys and hilarity ensures as the soldiers armed with blanks try to evade the locals armed with live ammo. Check it out.